# Cider spaces/wraps text as desired. Emulator/device do not

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, xaml

Cider (the Visual Studio XAML display) is wrapping and spacing my text correctly, the WP emulator and actual WP devices do not. (Tested in Silverlight, WP7, WP8, VS2010, VS2012). My desire is the have the text displayed in an exactly as it is in Cider. Please see the graphic below:

[image]

It's simple to reproduce. Just add the following to a page.

```
<Canvas Background="#000000" Width="480" Height="648" x:Name="Slide">
    <Canvas Canvas.Left="5.76" Canvas.Top="0" Name="callout" Width="342" Height="104.56999969482422">
        <Path StrokeLineJoin="Round" Fill="#E51400" Data="M0,17.43A17.43,17.43 0 0 1 17.43,0L199.5,0L199.5,0L285,0L324.57,0A17.43,17.43 0 0 1 342,17.43L342,61L365.94,74.51L342,87.14L342,87.14A17.43,17.43 0 0 1 324.57,104.57L285,104.57L199.5,104.57L199.5,104.57L17.43,104.57A17.43,17.43 0 0 1 0,87.14L0,87.14L0,61L0,61Z"/>
        <TextBlock Canvas.Top="8.7" Canvas.Left="12.3" Width="324.6" Height="90.76" LineHeight="28.8" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFFFFF" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" FontSize="24">
            <Run Text="It's overlapping. It's all spilling over the edge. One word, two syllables. Demarcation." />
        </TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

You can ignore the `<Path/>` object as it's only there to show how this looks when laid out. I've tried everything I can think of `LayoutRounding="False"`, etc. Nothing seems to work.

In a Silverlight project (not a WP8 project), the text displays incorrectly both in Cider and in the Silverlight add-in in the webpage.

Is there a way to make the text appear in an app (emulator, device) as it does in Cider for a WP8 project?

Comment: I just tried with VS2010 + WP7 and VS2012 + WP7, in both cases my designer wraps the text exactly like the emulator. Could you show us the full XAML of your page? Especially the `d:` attributes. These attributes are directives interpreted only by the designer, so they can explain layout differences with the emulator.

Comment: No `d:` attributes whatsoever just `<UserControl x:Class="Dwight.Slide1" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">`. VS2010 wraps like emulator, VS2012+WP7 does not.